# Present PFSignUpViewController manually: Parse Framework iOS

Tags: ios, parse-platform, pfloginviewcontroller

I'm using PFLoginViewController and instead of presenting it modally, I am presenting it as a subview so I can have a nice translucent background:

[image]

The only issue is that when I select Sign Up, it presents my Sign Up view controller modally which according to my console log, isn't the smartest idea: `Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged`

So what I would like to do is use a separate method for displaying my sign up view controller.  I tried this:

```
[loginView.logInView.signUpButton  addTarget:self action:@selector(presentSignUpView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

But the original Parse method was being called with my custom method being called in addition.  I looked at the docs and there is no delegate method for adding your own custom method so how should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you try to change here "presentSignUpView:"

```
[loginView.logInView.signUpButton  addTarget:self action:@selector(presentSignUpView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

For custom view First make a function that can call you for custom view open like this

```
-(void)customSignUpViewOpen{
  //Implement your custom view controller code here ..   
}
```

**Updated**   remove target before add  ..

```
[loginView.logInView.signUpButton  removeTarget:self action:@selector(presentSignUpView:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

and Call this in your button clicked like this

```
[loginView.logInView.signUpButton  addTarget:self action:@selector(customSignUpViewOpen) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: Yes.  It will call `customSignUpViewOpen` but it will also call the code parse has written in their framework so essentially I would be presenting my sign up view twice and in two different ways in this case.

Comment: It unfortunately did not work.  It could be that `presentSignUpView:` is not the right selector.  Is there a way to print to the console what selectors are being called?

Comment: I used a modified version of your answer and used this: `[loginView.logInView.signUpButton  addTarget:nil action:null forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllEvents];`  and then added the custom selector.  Thanks @Joge!